# Using Python to access SQL with a variable column name

Tags: python, mysql, sql, pymysql

I'm to link my code to a MySQL database using pymysql. In general everything has gone smoothly but I'm having difficulty with the following function to find the minimum of a variable column.

```py
def findmin(column):
    cur = db.cursor()
    sql = "SELECT MIN(%s) FROM table"
    cur.execute(sql,column)
    mintup = cur.fetchone()
```

if everything went smoothly this would return me a tuple with the minimum, e.g. `(1,)`.

However, if I run the function:

```
findmin(column_name)
```

I have to put column name in `""` (i.e. `"column_name"`), else Python sees it as an unknown variable. But if I put the quotation marks around `column_name` then SQL sees

```
SELECT MIN("column_name") FROM table
```

which just returns the column header, not the value.

How can I get around this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is likely the use of `%s` for the column name. That means the *SQL Driver* will try to escape that variable when interpolating it, including quoting, which is not what you want for things like column names, table names, etc.

When using a **value** in `SELECT`, `WHERE`, etc. then you do want to use `%s` to prevent *SQL injections* and enable quoting, among other things.

Here, you just want to interpolate using pure Python (assuming a **trusted value**; please see below for more information). That also means no bindings tuple passed to the `execute` method.

```py
def findmin(column):
    cur = db.cursor()
    sql = "SELECT MIN({0}) FROM table".format(column)
    cur.execute(sql)
    mintup = cur.fetchone()
```

SQL fiddle showing the SQL working:

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e70a41/1

**In response to the Jul 15, 2014 comment from Colin Phipps (September 2022):**

The relatively recent edit on this post by another community member  brought it to my attention, and I wanted to respond to Colin's comment from many years ago.

I totally agree re: being careful about one's input if one interpolates like this. Certainly one needs to know exactly what is being interpolated. In this case, I would say a defined value within a **trusted internal** script or one supplied by a **trusted internal** source would be fine. But if, as Colin mentioned, there is any external input, then that is much different and additional precautions should be taken.

Comment: This solution does assume that the column name is a trusted input (no escaping/validation performed). If you are writing, say, a website and this input comes from the user then you should validate it against a whitelist before including it in SQL in this way.

Comment: Thanks thats really helpful, worked a treat. Also @Colin thanks for the tip. Cheers all!